# Something is off with my code, can't find it

Tags: java, character

For some reason the code below isn't working properly. This is just the structure of the code but what I'm trying to make here is a one-on-one fighting game. You pick a character from 3 different options and battle against the computer, who also picked a character. The one who reaches 0 HP loses.

So the problem in this code is that the computer wins in every scenario. I just put character3 as my character, made it overpowered (1000 HP, 20 strength compared to 120HP and 8 strength), but my character is still losing. I'm guessing the problem is really simple, but I just can't see it/figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args){

    Character character1 = new Character("Test1", 100, 10);
    Character character2 = new Character("Test2", 120, 8);
    Character character3 = new Character("Test3", 1000, 20);

    Character player = character3;
    Character enemy = character2;

    boolean playersTurn = true;
    while (player.getHP() > 0 || enemy.getHP() > 0){
      if (playersTurn == true){
      enemy.damage(player.getStrength());
      } else {
      player.damage(enemy.getStrength());
      }
      playersTurn = !playersTurn;
    }
    if (player.getHP() > 0){
      System.out.println("Player won!");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Enemy won!");
    }
  }
}

class Character{

  protected String name;
  protected int HP;
  protected int strength;

  public Character(String name, int HP, int strength){
    this.name = name;
    this.HP = HP;
    this.strength = strength;
  }

  public String getName(){
    return this.name;
  }

  public int getHP(){
    return this.HP;
  }

  public int getStrength(){
    return this.strength;
  }

  public void damage(int amount){
    int sum = this.HP - amount;
    this.HP = sum;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding class names that are identical to those in the JRE, especially one in the java.lang package (eg `Character`)

Answer (score 3):

try changing

```
while (player.getHP() > 0 || enemy.getHP() > 0){
```

to

```
while (player.getHP() > 0 && enemy.getHP() > 0){
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while (player.getHP() > 0 || enemy.getHP() > 0)
```

lets the game go on so long as at least one of this is true:

- player's HP is > 0
- or enemy's HP is > 0

but you want the game to finish as soon as one of the two players is dead, or said in other words, you want the game to go on while both of the players still are alive, so

```
while (player.getHP() > 0 && enemy.getHP() > 0)
```

Moreover random component is missing in your code, the game will always be the same: you're importing the `Random` class but never using it

Answer (score 2):

Replace your while loop condition with

while (player.getHP() > 0 && enemy.getHP() > 0)

AND instead of OR